# Title overlapping page when using pdfpages

Tags: pdfpages, appendix

I'm trying to include a printed Google forms form as a part of an appendix using the following commands:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter 1}
Some text here, maybe even a \pagebreak

\appendix

\includepdf[pages={1}, scale=0.5,,pagecommand={\thispagestyle{plain}\chapter{Kysymyspatteri}}]{kysymyspatteri.pdf}
\includepdf[pages={2}, scale=1,,pagecommand={\thispagestyle{plain}}]{kysymyspatteri.pdf}
\end{document}
```

On the first included page the chapter title overlaps the included page, which ends up looking like this:

[image]

Is there any way I could fix this. Scaling the page down does nothing, as it scales down the chapter title with the page, maintaining it on top of the page.

Comment: It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem. While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Comment: There, a MWE added. You do  need a PDF document of your own, though.

Comment: In case you can cut away the very top of the pdf where your browser printed the web address, you can probably increase the size a bit

Comment: Yeah, I might end up doing just that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your included document is still readable at a scale of 0.5, you could simply move it a bit down to be below the chapter title:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter 1}
Some text here, maybe even a \pagebreak

\appendix

\includepdf[
    pages={1}, 
    scale=0.5,
    offset=0 -80,
    pagecommand={\thispagestyle{plain}\chapter{Kysymyspatteri}}
]{example-image-a4-numbered.pdf}

\end{document}
```

[image]